# Updated pacman gnupg keys (Arch Linux) now ssh connections refused immediately

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, sshd

Arch Linux. Had problem installing `git` e.g.

```
pacman -S git
...
error: key "6D42BDD116E0068F" could not be looked up remotely
error: required key missing from keyring
```

So I tried updating keys, and continued to get errors e.g.

```
pacman -S archlinux-keyring
...
downloading required keys...
error: key "6D42BDD116E0068F" could not be looked up remotely
error: required key missing from keyring
```

So I did this...

```
cd /etc/pacman.d
mv gnupg gnupg.bak
pacman-key --init
pacman-key --populate archlinux
pacman-key --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:11371 --recv-keys 6D42BDD116E0068F
```

Now I can't `ssh` into that host. `ssh` connections are refused immediately.

```
ssh -vvv root@some.ip.address
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname some.ip.address is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to some.ip.address [some.ip.address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to some.ip.address:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:62
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from some.ip.address
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:pok7LaonIrLfcKdCqrCvA/+buuwrgQ5I0Ra5Ucwaj28
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:62
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from some.ip.address
debug1: Host 'some.ip.address' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:62
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:QDDDb/mIVePAQQdPUmjXKhEkeU+S7Tr6qBcY+m5XAKg
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
Connection closed by some.ip.address port 22
```

I'm not sure what changed. I can get into the host using Linode's LISH console, so I can get in to affect changes, but I don't know why the connection is being refused, and I don't know why updating `pacman` keys should have had any effect like this.

What might be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Run `journalctl -elf` on the server and try to login via ssh. If that produces too much noise, try `journalctl -elf -u ssh` instead. Since you are logging in via key-based authentication, what are the permissions on the user's ssh files on the server (`namei -m ~/.ssh/*`)?

Comment: Using `journalctl` it seems that nothing is being logged on the server side. On the client side still getting immediate disconnection. 

One user has 700 for `namei -m ~/.ssh/*`, that is ` drwx------ .ssh`. The root user has no such directory as `.ssh`.

Comment: Solved problem by updating `libxcrypt` and `openssh` via `pacman`. Root cause still unknown.